# Zener diodes in high frequencies

Tags: high-frequency, zener

Why don't they use zener diodes in high frequencies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In reverse biased mode, which is how you would normally use a zener, the capacitance is tens to hundreds of picofarads. This could be enough to attenuate your signal significantly, depending on the frequency and source impedance.

Comment: The large-ish capacitance of a Zener is one of the reasons they need alternative architectures for ESD protection on very high-speed data lines.

Comment: @Martin- Is there a relationship mobility of holes in PN junction?

Comment: @Cell-o, you'll have to look that up. As a practising engineer, I haven't had the need to use zeners with anything approaching RF so the theoretical reason for the capacitance isn't something that springs to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Zener diodes aren't typically used in a signal path. You won't find them easily in lower frequency paths either. They're used mostly to control DC voltages.